# Is it possible to remove root access on a directory in OSX?

Tags: macos, permissions, root

In OSX, is it possible to make a directory not accessible by root, but accessible to another user? So something like a `sudo rm /directory` wouldn't work but `su otheruser; rm /directory` would. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, root on Unix systems is always granted full access; regular access control simply does not apply. You cannot prevent root from deleting a file. Even if you could, root would still be able to switch to any other account including the one who can delete it. (Mandatory access control systems like TrustedBSD *might* be able to restrict root, but I don't think OS X has that.)

*(I may be wrong)*